# How to download file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, file, axios, download

I am calling exernal api with post data, and response is coming as

`Conte-type: image/svg+xml transfer-encoding: chunked`

How can i save this file to local?

This is backend, not frontend.

Thank you

I am using axios for api call.

Comment: I tried it, but as i mentioned, it is backend thing, not frontend, and i want to save to local file

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following code and it's working on my local machine. You can try the following code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "randomFileUrl.png",
    responseType: "stream"
}).then(function (response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./randomFileName.png"));
}).catch(err => {
    // do something with the error
    console.log({ err });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as i mentioned, it is post and if i put responseType as stream, it is coming as error

Comment: @Ultimate can you share a sample file URL?

Comment: it is not file, just post data, with proper parameters, and it returns image

Comment: ok. Is there any scope for it so that I can reproduce the response on my machine? I would love to do some experiments.

Comment: actually, it is using api key so i can't share it, 
but simply, you can try,
make a simple express backend, to return image as response (image/png)